# Lorentz invariance of the axial current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices

I want to determine whether

$$\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \gamma^5 \psi \bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu \gamma^5\psi = j_5^\mu j_{5\mu},$$
where $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 $ and $\gamma^5 = -i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$,
is Lorentz invariant.

I know that under Lorentz transformation:

$$\psi \rightarrow S[\Lambda]\psi \space \space\space, \space\space\space \bar{\psi} \rightarrow \psi^\dagger \gamma^0{S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^0\gamma^0 = \bar{\psi}{S[\Lambda]}^{-1}$$

So I'm left with something that looks like:

$$\bar{\psi}{S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^\mu \gamma^5 S[\Lambda]\psi \bar{\psi}{S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma_\mu \gamma^5S[\Lambda]\psi$$

But what do I do next? It looks like I require

$${S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^\mu \gamma^5 S[\Lambda] = 1$$

where $1$ is just the unit matrix. Or perhaps that the downstairs and upstairs terms transform in opposite ways. How do I show this?

Comment: You surely learned about the Lorentz transformation properties of the γ matrices when you were introduce to them, no?

Comment: Well, I know that ${S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^\mu S[\Lambda] = \Lambda^\mu_\nu\gamma^\nu$ but then what do I do with the product of two gammas? Also, could I not just commute the rightmost $\gamma^\mu\gamma^5$ to the left, past the fields, and then just anti-commute and multiply them out with the other gammas? I'd get $\gamma^\mu \gamma^5\gamma_\mu \gamma_5 = -\gamma^5\gamma^\mu\gamma_\mu\gamma^5$. Now I'd use $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = \eta^{\mu\nu}$. Would that work?

Comment: What do you do with the product of the two vectors on the right hand side? Taking the γ s past the spinor fields does not saturate their spinor indices with those of other such,  to yield matrix multiplication as you are proposing, perhaps alarmingly.

Comment: I see. Back to transformation properties then, I suppose. I could insert $S[\Lambda]{S[\Lambda]}^{-1}$ in between the two $\gamma$s, then I could use the transformation property. But then I'm still left with the ${S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^5 S[\Lambda]$. Am I doing the right thing, trying to figure out the transformation relation for  $\gamma^5$?

Comment: Yes. (Ignore these extra characters required to allow this comment to post.)

Comment: One thing I can do is, since ${S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^\mu S[\Lambda] = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu$, is to expand $\gamma^5=-i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$ and use particular elements of the transformation property, such as ${S[\Lambda]}^{-1}\gamma^0 S[\Lambda] = \Lambda^0_\nu \gamma^\nu$. But then I'm left with a bunch of $\Lambda$ and $\gamma$ matrices and they don't immediately look like they're going to reduce... Any hints on transforming $\gamma^5$?